# Why do odd numbers of either of the nucleons in a nucleus make it relatively unstable compared to a nucleus having even numbers of both the nucleons?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Try to keep it as simple as possible, as I am still completing school. Just wanted to get an explanation.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_atomic_nuclei and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model

Answer (score 1):

There is no solid theory on why the occurrence of even number of either nucleons in a nucleus of an atom is stable. Only through experimental data have we been able to observe this phenomenon and the concept of magic numbers.

Even some approximations and theories such as Semi-empirical mass formula fail to explain this occurrence.

But we cannot generalize this observation for all elements as some  odd-odd stable isotopes are also present, for example :

2H1, 6Li3, 10B5, 14N7